# How i can get the country names from large data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How to extract country names out of the data?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhe97.jpg]

Comment: No way. If you have predefined lists of country then you can get country name from cell.

Comment: I will make that list, then how could I extract country names from the data.

Comment: Perhap you coild try the find() function...

Comment: Have you made the list of countries yet?

Answer (score 1):

First make a list of countries -preferably- to another sheet. Below screenshot is a sample list which is on **Sheet2**:

[image: country list]

Assuming that your data is located as below, write below formula to `B1` of your **Sheet1** and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to activate the array formula.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5,A1))*ROW(Sheet2!$1:$5)))
```

[image: data & formula]

- If your country list has more than 5 items, then you should be changing your formula's `Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5` & `ROW(Sheet2!$1:$5)` parts accordingly.

Comment: the country list is not in the manner you showed, it is in haphazard manner.

Comment: I am not sure what does "haphazard" mean in this sense but you should be somehow organizing your list into columns, into rows or into a CSV format in order to use these list items programatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'As far as I know this task can be achieve if we have list of all country.
'here CountyText.text file contain list of all country.
'for demo this list collect from internet you can add your own list in this file.
'This function can be use where compitational time doesn't matter.
'Before use this function copy paste this code in new module.

Function FindCountry(cellstring As String) As String
Dim DataLine As String
Dim File As String
File = "D:\CountyText.txt" 'Path of county text file
'(for demo this list collect from internet) you can add your own list in this file
FindCountry = "" 'initial value of function

On Error Resume Next 'this is for error handling
Close #1
Open File For Input As #1
On Error GoTo 0

While Not EOF(1) 'while end of file
    Line Input #1, DataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
If InStr(cellstring, DataLine) Then
FindCountry = DataLine
End If
Wend

Close #1
End Function
```

to write countryText.txt file format see screenshots

[image: countryText.txt]

[image: OutPut]

After adding "USA" in countryText.txt file it can be identify

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose you have country list from `J1` to `J5` like below screenshot.

   [image]
2. In a module copy and paste the below function. See screenshot.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public Function getCountry(ByVal srtText As String) As String
   Dim CountryArray As Variant
   Dim i As Long

       Application.Volatile
       CountryArray = Application.Transpose(Range("J1:J5").Value2)
       For i = LBound(CountryArray) To UBound(CountryArray)
           If (InStr(1, srtText, CountryArray(i), 1)) > 0 Then
               getCountry = CountryArray(i)
               Exit Function
           End If
       Next i
   End Function
   ```

   [image]

   3. Then use following function in `B1` cell.

      ```
      =getCountry(A1)
      ```

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula in cell `B2` like below:

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(CountryList,A2,1),CountryList)`

> where `CountryList` refers to the range holding names of countries you are looking for!